# What's the point of closing a question after it has accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, closing

Like this: [What's the value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty{\frac {1}{x}}\sin \left({\frac {1}{x^{3}}}\right)dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044636/whats-the-value-of-int-infty-infty-frac-1x-sin-left-frac-1x)

Whether it is closed or not, the result is already obtained, so what the closure is intended to prevent? Other answers? Well, if somebody would write another and better answer, what's bad with it?

Comment: related https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/why-close-old-questions-with-accepted-answers-using-the-no-context-reason

Comment: Somewhat similar older post here on meta: [What's the point to put/keep “On Hold” a question that has already an accepted answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11203) There is also the [thread pointed out by @AlbusDumbledore](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19377) (and a few more related to the same topic), but to me that seems a bit different. (The question linked in the example was posted less than a week ago, I would not call that an *old* question.)

Comment: Users often post answers *very* quickly, whereas the process of closing a question tends to run slower.  Are you suggesting that if a "fastest gun in the west" posts an answer before the review process has had a chance to work, that the question should be preserved?

Answer (score 16):

Closed questions can be deleted more easily. They also send a message to the other users of the site "this is not how you are expected to ask a question".

Moreover, closed questions contribute to "negative participation score" which can lead to rate limits (e.g., being blocked from asking questions for some time).

So yes, bad questions should be closed, and if no effort is made to improve them, also downvoted and deleted. If nothing else, then to rid the website of their preserve and eventually of users who consistently ask badly written questions.